# Deriving $[\dot P^e(\tau)+\lambda P^e(\tau)]e^{\lambda\tau} = \frac{d}{d\tau} P^e(\tau)e^{\lambda\tau}$

Tags: derivatives

I have mathematical question.

[image]

[image]

in this image, why left side of above equation is equal with left side of below equation?

can you explain in detail expression..?

Comment: Seems quite off-topic to me. I've voted for migration. By the way, the title is useless in any forum but especially in a mathematical forum: please replace it by something more specific. What's AEH and why is anyone who knows about ordinary differential equations expected to know what it means?

Comment: No need to know; all you need to do is see that it's an application of the product rule.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try it differentiating back to see the result.

This is a simple extension of $\frac{d}{dt}(xy) = x \frac{dy}{dt} + y \frac{dx}{dt}$

$ \frac{d}{d \tau} P_{e}(\tau)e^{\lambda t} \implies$
$\dot P_{e}(\tau)e^{\lambda \tau}$ +  $P_{e}(\tau) \frac{d}{d \tau}e^{\lambda \tau} \implies $ $\dot P_{e}(\tau)e^{\lambda t}$ +  $\lambda P_{e}(\tau)e^{\lambda \tau}$  $\implies$ $e^{\lambda \tau}(\dot P_{e}(\tau) + \lambda P_{e}(\tau))$